# How to get Modules list in symfony

Tags: methods, symfony1, module

I am new to symfony and I am learning it. I want to get all working modules and their methods dynamically to bulild a list to implement ACL.

```
foreach(getModules() as $module)
{
   echo $moudule .' has following methods: '; 
   foreach( $module as $method )
   {
       echo $method.'<br />';
   }
}
```

Above code is not a valid code. it is just an idea to get things.

Comment: Could you explain more of why you need this list? There maybe an easier solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Symfony 1 doesn't (as far as I can find) maintain a list of all modules during runtime. For performance reasons, it only tries to load one when it's called. You could try something dirty like parsing the autoloader cache, but I wouldn't recommend it.

I assume you want the list so that you can build an admin UI for your ACL tool. The alternative approach is to retrieve a list of routes, which is definitely possible, e.g. `sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->getRoutes()`.

If you want your ACLs to apply to specific classes or objects, rather than URLs or actions, then I suggest moving to [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) which has [this functionality](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) built in.

Answer (score 2):

You can index all the modules of your application using native code.
You can use an action or a component to do this.
Here's the code:

```
  $this->modulos = array();

  $aplicacion = "admin"; //The name of your symfony app
  $directorio = opendir("../apps/$aplicacion/modules");
  while($file = readdir($directorio)){
      if($file=="..")continue;
      if($file==".")continue;
      // here you can filter the modules
      $this->modulos[] = $file;
  }
```

... and the template:

```
<?php foreach($modulos as $modulo):?>
    <div>
        <?php echo link_to($modulo,"@default?module=$modulo&action=index") ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now, you have a list of all your modules.